# How can I split a string containing multiple js statements into an array of strings each string containing one statement?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a string containing a number of JavaScript statements separated by ";".
I need to split this into an array of strings with each string containing an individual command.

I cannot simply use the string splitting function with ";" as the delimiter because ";" also exist in the other commands within strings.

**How can I split a string containig multiple js statements into an array of strings each string containing an individual command?**

For example I can have something like:

```
    $('_32123').innerHTML="<div  style=\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-
bottom:5px;text-align:right;\" id=\"_134607\"   noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'>
    </div>";document.onkeydown = function(event) { if (event.ctrlKey && 
event.keyCode == 89) Event(3160,'Refresh',{ q:'' }); };
```

Is there a library or something that can provide this functionality or how else can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you say "commands" are you talking about javascript _statements_?  If so, it's not as trivial as just splitting by `;`, there's much more than that to parsing a language

Comment: if parse the given example string, what should be the output? by the way, please fix the ":" typo, it sometimes confuse people...

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes I meant statements. Sorry English isn't my first language.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis I have corrected the typo

Comment: you can hack jsmin, it's a super small "parser" without the full complication of an AST. basically, right before it outputs, it has an array of strings of code, and any string literals in that array will be their own elements, with quotes. that means that by looping through the array and playing "duck duck goose", you can process only the strings or non-strings with ~100% reliability. the only thing it doesn't support, afaik, is multi-line strings using the escape operator before line breaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regular expression will be too simple to split the JavaScript code into statements. This could be made working though for simple things, but there's JavaScript strings, JavaScript regexes and comments which make this more complex. Additionally, JavaScript constructs are not necessarily ending with semicolons. Consider this:

```
if (foo) { throw "bar"; }
```

Though `throw "bar";` ends with semicolon, it is unclear whether you want to capture the whole if statement with its body or just the `throw` parts.
Apart from that, JavaScript statements may also end at a newline. The following are two valid JavaScript statements, though not separated by semicolons:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

In order to deal with all these complex rules, you will need a language-aware parser. There are several JavaScript-parsing frameworks out there, and you have to choose a parser framework that suits you.

Following is an example for tokenizing the statements with [Acorn](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn). I ran the following code in nodejs after installing acorn with `npm install acorn`:

```
var code = "$('_32123').innerHTML=\"<div style=\\\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\\\" id=\\\"_134607\\\"   noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>\";document.onkeydown = function(event) { if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 89) Event(3160,'Refresh',{ q:'' }); };";

var acorn = require("acorn");
var tokens = acorn.parse(code);

tokens.body.forEach(function(token) {
  console.log("statement: ", code.substr(token.start, token.end - token.start));
});
```

This will print the two top-level statements in the example code.

Note that the example JavaScript code you supplied has only two top-level statements (the two assignment expressions), but more than two statements in total. For example, there is also a function declaration and an if statement. These statements are sub-statements of the two top-level statements.

If you want to capture all these statements (top-level and sub-statements) in isolation, you will need to walk the abstract syntax tree generated by the parser and also recurse into subtokens. Going recursive is also necessary because JavaScript allows having nested structures (control structures, functions).

This will easily get a bit more complicated because you have to handle the different subtoken types. Here's an example implementation handling only a few types that demonstrates how the AST can be walked:

```
var code = "$('_32123').innerHTML=\"<div style=\\\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\\\" id=\\\"_134607\\\"   noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>\";document.onkeydown = function(event) { if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 89) Event(3160,'Refresh',{ q:'' }); };";

var acorn = require("acorn");
var tokens = acorn.parse(code);

function recursiveDump(token, level) {
  var pad = Array(level).join("  "); 
  console.log(pad + "- token");
  console.log(pad + "  - type: " + token.type);
  console.log(pad + "  - code: " + code.substr(token.start, token.end - token.start));

  if (token.type === 'ExpressionStatement') {
    if (token.expression.left) {
      console.log(pad + "  - children:");
      recursiveDump(token.expression.left, level + 3);
      recursiveDump(token.expression.right, level + 3);
      console.log(); 
    }
  }
  else if (token.type === 'IfStatement') {
    console.log(pad + "  - children:");
    recursiveDump(token.test, level + 3);
    recursiveDump(token.consequent, level + 3);
    if (token.alternate !== null) {
      recursiveDump(token.alternate, level + 3);
    }
    console.log();
  }
  else if (token.hasOwnProperty("body")) {
    console.log(pad + "  - children:");
    var body = token.body;
    if (! Array.isArray(body) && body.hasOwnProperty("body")) {
      body = body.body;
    }

    body.forEach(function(token) {
      recursiveDump(token, level + 3);
    });
    console.log();
  }
}

tokens.body.forEach(function(token) {
  recursiveDump(token, 0);
});
```

This was just a quick example of how to process subtokens in general. You can save all this work if you only need to handle top-level statements.

Comment: I only need the top level statements and all of them end with ";" this is a rule specific to the application. Thank you very much for you answer I will try it.

Comment: my javascript is client side in the browser. Is there any way to use this in such an environment?

Comment: Seems so: quoting from https://github.com/marijnh/acorn: "When run in a CommonJS (node.js) or AMD environment, exported values appear in the interfaces exposed by the individual files, as usual. When loaded in the browser (Acorn works in any JS-enabled browser more recent than IE5) without any kind of module management, a single global object acorn will be defined, and all the exported properties will be added to that."

Comment: tried including it like so <script src='acorn.js' type='text/javascript'></script> and got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã...(too long to print it here). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have used `npm install acorn` on my local machine first, which generates a script `dist/acorn.js`. This can be loaded from the browser as follows: `<script type="text/javascript" src="acorn.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`. Note that the `charset` attribute is required because the script contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem to work now at least under some conditions. If I have something like $('_32123').innerHTML=\"<div  style=\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\" id='_134607'   noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>\" it throws an error on the second escaped double quote. The exception is "Unexpected token (1:36)". Is there a way of making it work regardless? If not I think I can make it only use single quotes.

Comment: I think the parser is correct when it throws an exception, because the code above is no valid JavaScript. It should rather be: `$('_32123').innerHTML="<div style=\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\" id='_134607' noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>";` (have a look at the surrounding quotes, which mustn't be escaped, and the quotes contained inside the string, which must be escaped).

Comment: The way it works is I get this string from the server side code. So I have an ajax request $.ajax and onsuccess I receive the server side output which in my case is javascript code that should be evaluated. so I have a js variable called responseText and it's value is "$('_32123').innerHTML=\"<div style=\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\" id='_134607' noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>\"". The way I see it this is perfectly ok.

Comment: I still think it's invalid JavaScript code. Please try running `console.log("$('_32123').innerHTML=\"<div style=\"font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;\" id='_134607' noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>\"");` in your browser to print the string with JavaScript. This should print `$('_32123').innerHTML="<div style="font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;" id='_134607' noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>"`, which is the code you'll parse. That code assigns a string to innerHTML and the string is `"<div style="`...

Comment: ...and after that, the string is finished, and the script continues with `font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;` which is not valid JavaScript, and thus parsing fails. If you don't believe me, try running this in JavaScript to see that it won't parse: `$('_32123').innerHTML="<div style="font-size:11px;margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:right;" id='_134607' noprint='no' noprintoverflow='no'></div>"`